# Get value from Cloud Firebase and show element depends of if/else statement

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get value from Cloud Firebase database and use if/else statement to show or hide some div elements, depends of that value. My database works fine, I can save, read and delate data but I can't find solution where I should use this conditional logic. Can I do that with this code, can anyone write me where is a problem, why this doesn't work?

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const db = firebase.firestore();

db.collection('ringnum').get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        renderRingNumbers(doc);
    })
})

db.collection('ringnum').get().then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot=='1'){
        document.getElementById('ring').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('ring2').style.display='none';
    }else if (snapshot=='2'){
        document.getElementById('ring').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('ring2').style.display='block';
    }
})
```

Comment: You have to extract the contents of the snapshot before comparing; like `var data = doc.data();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some conditional logic based on the `data.` but you extract the `data` and apply your logic on the attribute. If you want to show/hide the divs based on attribute `someField` you can do something like:

```
query.get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        var data = doc.data();
        if(data.someField == 1){
            document.getElementById('ring').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('ring2').style.display='none';
        }else if(data.someField == 2){
            document.getElementById('ring').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('ring2').style.display='block';
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, my code looks now:

```
db.collection('ringnum').get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        renderRingNumbers(doc);
        var data = doc.data();
        if(data.ringSelect == 1){
            document.getElementById('ring').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('ring2').style.display='none';
        }else if(data.ringSelect == 2){
            document.getElementById('ring').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('ring2').style.display='block';
        }
    })
})
```

I lost realtime listener now, my code was:

```
db.collection('ringnum').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
    changes.forEach( change => {
        if(change.type == 'added'){
            renderRingNumbers(change.doc)
        } else if (change.type == 'removed'){
            let li = ringnumList.querySelector('[data-id=' + change.doc.id + ']');
            ringnumList.removeChild(li);
        }
    })
```

So, anyone knows how to edit it to get realtime listener for show/hide divs? Thanks!

Comment: You can replace `db.collection('ringnum').get().then((snapshot) => {...}` with `db.collection('ringnum').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {...}`